# Tizen Studio No Thumb

Tags: arm, tizen, thumb

I'm using Tizen Studio and I'd like to compile Mobile 3.0 Native Application without Thumb. However, when I build app with Debug configuration, I see -mthumb flag and I have no idea how to delete it.

Tizen Studio 2.0

Comment: Are you sure about Tizen Studio Version? So far I know, Version 1.2 is released till now. Where did you find Version 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using Tizen Studio 1.2
You could use a different optimization level to see if the mthumb goes away.
RightClick on your project.
C/C++ Build -> Settings -> C/C++ Compiler -> Optimizations
(default is set to -O3)
You can try experimenting and figure out the level you need.